# Preventing a possible PostgreSQL GUC parameter race condition?

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing, race-condition, postgresql-12

Let's say I have two db clients executing queries against a PostgreSQL cluster in parallel. I decide that I want one of them to use [max_parallel_workers_per_gather](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PARALLEL-WORKERS-PER-GATHER) at 2 and the other at 6.

So, client #1 will do

```
exec("SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather=2; // A
SELECT * FROM large_scan; // B
");
```

Client #2 will do

```
exec("SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather=6; // C
SELECT * FROM other_large_scan; // D
");
```

I am expecting sequence A->B->C->D so that both B and D execute at the same time with specified parameter. But is the sequence A->C->B->D possible? That would give 6 to both clients which is not what I want!

I am using [SPI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/spi.html) which I believe does not support asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a parameter in a session is generally local to that session.  The execution order can be A->C->B->D, but that doesn't mean B will pay attention to what C did.